# How do you calculate this integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ {e^{e^{\sin x}}}dx $

Tags: integration

> Evaluate the  Integral: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\ {e^{e^{\sin x}}}\ dx $$

I'm curious as to whether or not this integral has been solved and if solved how to go on about it.

Comment: Why would you expect there to be a symbolic solution?

Comment: I plan on solving it, just want to know if anyone has already done it first.

Comment: There might be a way of using complex analysis.

Comment: Consider adding your thoughts and attempts in your question.

Comment: Not all integrals are "solvable". Your solution is approximately $31.785$ as pointed out in Ross' answer, but there might not be a symbolic, analytical solution. It can be unsolvable.

Comment: You may expand the outer exponential as a Maclaurin series, then exploit $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\exp(m\sin x)\,dx = 2\pi I_0(m) $ where $I_0$ is the principal modified Bessel function of the first kind.

Answer (score 2):

You can feed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5E(e%5E(sin%20x))%20from%20-pi%20to%20pi), getting a result that say the integral is aobut $31.785$  I would be amazed if there is an analytic solution and expect that this is a numerical answer.  The fact that an exact form was not offered supports this.  It is easy to write integrals that cannot be solved analytically.